# Canon T3i remote control minus self timer

Tags: canon, remote, self-timer

How do I turn on the infrared remote capability, but turn off the 10 second self timer on my Canon T3i?

Comment: Which remote are you using? The RC-6, the RC-5, or the (older) RC-1?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I turn on the infrared remote capability, but turn off the 10 second self timer on my Canon T3i?

In timer/remote mode the camera will fire *either* 10 seconds after you press the shutter release on the camera, or as soon as it autofocuses when you press the button on the remote. That is, if you use the remote, the camera won't wait 10 seconds, so there should be no need to disable the timer when using the remote.

Answer (score 1):

According to a similar question asked for Canon EOS 500D (Which is very similar to the T3i):

It depends on the IR remote model.

- Canon RC-1: has a slider in front between immediate and 2 sec delay.
- Canon RC-5: doesn't have any slider and works only at 2 sec delay.
- Canon RC-6: has a slider on the back to accomplish the same job as
  RC-1.

I guess the camera has also an option for 2seconds delay timer (with remote support).